# How to convert a tokenized dataframe to string to generate a wordcloud

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm reading an excel file to a dataframe and then normalizing it ( lowercase, stopwords..etc)

Now my dataframe has multiple columns from the excel file but only the ones I needed and it looks something like below. I had to tokenize it.

df['col1']

```
0 [this, is , fun, interesting]
1 [this, is, fun, too]
2 [ even, more, fun]
```

I have more similar columns like df['col2'] and so on.

Now I want to generate a word cloud

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
text = WordCloud().generate(df['col'])
plt.imshow(text)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

I'm trying to generate a wordcloud but this isn't working since apparently word cloud expects a string. How do I convert my entire dataframe to string?

I want to convert entire dataframe to string and then generate a wordcloud but if that's not possible then atleast a wordcloud per column would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to convert your columns to `string` as so far you only have a `list` of strings which `WordCloud` cannot take. Simply,

```
text = WordCloud().generate(df['col1'].to_string())
```

And your output image is
[image]

Comment: so simple yet I spent hours trying to figure this out. thanks

Comment: do you know how can I lammetize the above mentioned datframe with  nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer?

Answer (score 0):

You should first consider if you are processing your data right, it seems to defeat the purpose of tokenizing it and then putting it all together again.

If you have to do it anyways, you can get the values from your columns and use `chain` from the Python standard module library to chain them together, then join them to get a string representation of all the words.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[['this', 'is' , 'fun', 'interesting'],['this', 'is', 'fun', 'too'],['even','more']]})
word_list = list(chain.from_iterable(df.col1.values))
words = ' '.join(word_list)

words
>>'this is fun interesting this is fun too even more'
```

If this is done for multiple columns, you will have to append each of the column values together before you chain them.